# Grouping By in Linux inside a file

Tags: linux, unix, awk

i have a file named `VPN.txt` below:

```
VPN1 Human 1 Disconnected 
VPN1 Human 2 Disconnected
VPN1 Human 3 Is Connected
VPN2 Human 4 Connected
VPN3 Human 5 Disconnected
VPN3 Human 6 Connected 
VPN4 Human 7 Disconnected
VPN5 Human 8 Connected
```

then i hope to get the result like this:

```
VPN1 :
Human 1 Disconnected 
Human 2 Disconnected
Human 3 Is Connected

VPN2 : 
Human 4 Connected

VPN3 : 
Human 5 Disconnected
Human 6 Connected 

VPN4 : 
Human 7 Disconnected

VPN5 : 
Human 8 Connected
```

At the moment i'm starting with awk, i was able to get the count of each 
my current resul :

```
VPN1: 3
VPN2 : 1
VPN3 : 2
VPN4 : 1
VPN5 : 1
```

the function:

```
awk '{count[$1]++}END{for(j in count) print j":"count[j]}' VPN.txt
```

But it's not what i want to do instead of counting i want to group them in group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
{
  val=$1
  $1=""
  sub(/^ +/,"")
  a[val]=(a[val]?a[val] ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  for(i in a){
    print i":" ORS a[i]
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation of above code here.

```
awk '                                   ##Starting awk program from here.
{                                       ##Starting main BLOCK for this awk program from here.
  val=$1                                ##Creating val variable whose value is $1 of current line.
  $1=""                                 ##Nullifying $1 of current line here.
  sub(/^ +/,"")                         ##Substituting initial space with NULL here.
  a[val]=(a[val]?a[val] ORS:"")$0       ##Creating array a whose index is variable val and value is current line value.
}                                       ##Closing main BLOCK of this program here.
END{                                    ##Starting END BLOCK of this awk program here.
  for(i in a){                          ##Starting a for loop to traverse through array a here.
    print i":" ORS a[i]                 ##Printing variable i colon ORS and value of array a with variable i here.
  }                                     ##Closing for loop previous BLOCK here.
}                                       ##Closing BLOCK for END section of this awk program here.
'  Input_file                           ##Mentioning Input_file name here
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** In case if you want to have output in same order in which Input_file's 1st field is occurring then you could try following.

```
awk '
{
  val=$1
  $1=""
  sub(/^ +/,"")
}
!c[val]++{
  d[++count]=val
}
{
  a[val]=(a[val]?a[val] ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print d[i]":" ORS a[d[i]]
  }
}
'   Input_file
```

Comment: THIS IS IT my life savor

Comment: Thank you soo much for commenting the code, it's more understandable. 

Do you have good resource please to learn more about awk ?

Comment: @StillLearningHowtodoit, your welcome, you could go through stack overflow threads itself there is lots of learning here cheers :)

Comment: @StillLearningHowtodoit, Here are 2 links `- https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf 2nd is: https://archive.org/details/pdfy-MgN0H1joIoDVoIC7 and finally a very nice link would be Stack overflow's https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info Lemme know if I could guide you more, will try my best to help here, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
prev!=$1 { prev=$1; printf "%s%s :%s", NR==1 ? "" : ORS, $1, ORS }
prev==$1 { for (i=2;i<=NF; i++){ printf "%s%s", $i, i==NF ? ORS : OFS} }
' file
```

- if the value of field1 changed (`prev!=$1`):

  - save its new value in variable `prev`
  - print a newline if it's not the first line (`ORS`= output field separator which is a newline)
  - print field1 followed by a space character, `:` and a newline
- if the value of field1 did not change:

  - print all fields except for the first field with a separator
  - if it's not the last field, use the output field separator `OFS` (a space character) as separator
  - if it's the last field, use a newline as separator

---

**Update**

A version that would match the "first field" if it contains an optional space character (yes, it would be field1 and field2, but let's call it "first field").

This assumes this first field only contains

- uppercase letters and digits
- or uppercase letters, a space character and digits

Change the regex as needed.

```
awk '
BEGIN { regex="^([A-Z0-9]+|[A-Z]+ [0-9]+)" }     # set regex to match "first field"
{ match($0, regex, a); f1=a[0] }                 # set "first field" as f1
prev!=f1 {
  prev=f1                                        # use f1 instead of $1 as previous field
  printf "%s%s :%s", NR==1 ? "" : ORS, prev, ORS # copy & paste from script above
}
prev==f1 { 
  sub(regex" ", "") # remove "first field" and the following space character from $0
  print             # print the line (now without "first field")
}' file
```

Comment: this is so clean, how to deal when there's space between VPN1 = VPN 1 , VPN 2 instead of VPN1,VPN2

Comment: See the update, it's not so clean any more. Change the regex as needed to match your names `VPN 1` etc.